# Try to get age from date in table but did not work. Error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, database, date, oracle-apex

I try to run and get the age from the date in a table but end up with error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected".

This is my first time run in apex oracle

shipping table

```
ship_id   ship_date

SEL0001   12/6/2015
SEL0002   01/5/2016
```

sql code

```
select ship_id, YEAR(ship_date) AS [BirthDate],
YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [ThisYear],
YEAR(GETDATE()) -YEAR(ship_date) AS Age
from shipping
```

expected output

```
ship_id   BirthDate    ThisYear   Age

SEL0001   12/6/2015     2020       5
SEL0002   01/5/2016     2020       4
```

Is there any way to get the age? I try to use datediff but I am not expert in that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `extract` in Oracle, here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7747e/5).

```
select 
  ship_id, 
  TO_CHAR(ship_date , 'MM/DD/YYYY') as BirthDate,
  extract(YEAR from sysdate) as ThisYear,
  extract(YEAR from sysdate) -  extract(YEAR from ship_date) as Age
from shipping
```

output:

```
*---------------------------------------*
| SHIP_ID   BIRTHDATE     THISYEAR  AGE |
*---------------------------------------*
| SEL0001   12/06/2015      2020     5  |
| SEL0002   01/05/2016      2020     4  |
*---------------------------------------*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` to get year or month value, and for age use the `months_between' to get the no.of months then calc age.

```
      select ship_id,
            to_char(ship_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') "BirthDate",
            extract(year from SYSDATE) ThisYear, 
             months_between(sydate,ship_date)/12 as Age_inYears
        from shipping
```